# How to get a screen image into a memory buffer?

Tags: c++, image, winapi, screen

I've been searching for a pure WIN32 way of getting the image data of a screen into a buffer, for analysis of the objects in the image later... Sadly I haven't found any. I'm now open to suggestions of libraries / classes that could do the "printing of a screen", but I should still have access to it's memory buffer.

Any help appreciated.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I will be capturing the screen continuously, so the operation speed is very important. Maybe someone knows a good library for this?

Comment: I'm sure someone will write this up properly, but for now here's an overview of using memory DCs that hits all the high points: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145049(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
// get screen DC and memory DC to copy to
HDC hScreenDC = GetDC(0);
HDC hMemoryDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hScreenDC);

// create a DIB to hold the image
BITMAPINFO bmi = { 0 };
bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(bmi.bmiHeader);
bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = GetDeviceCaps(hScreenDC, HORZRES);
bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = -GetDeviceCaps(hScreenDC, VERTRES);
bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
LPVOID pBits;
HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateDIBSection(hMemoryDC, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, &pBits, NULL, 0);

// select new bitmap into memory DC
HGDIOBJ hOldBitmap = SelectObject(hMemoryDC, hBitmap);

// copy from the screen to memory
BitBlt(hMemoryDC, 0, 0, bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth, -bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight, hScreenDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

// clean up
SelectObject(hMemoryDC, hOldBitmap);
DeleteDC(hMemoryDC);
ReleaseDC(0, hScreenDC);

// the image data is now in pBits in 32-bpp format
// free this when finished using DeleteObject(hBitmap);
```

Comment: Say I put this in a function. Would this be good enough for capturing the screen continuously ? If not, would "globalizing" some variables speedup the function?

Comment: @Cover Yes. If you're doing this more than once, you should "globalize" everything but the BitBlt. Keep in mind that if you do that, you'll have to respond correctly to display changes (if that's in the scope of your program).

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways (you could use DirectX), but probably the simplest and easiest is to use GDI.

```
    // GetDC(0) will return screen device context
    HDC hScreenDC = GetDC(0);
    // Create compatible device context which will store the copied image
    HDC hMyDC= CreateCompatibleDC(hScreenDC );

    // Get screen properties
    int iScreenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    int iScreenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
    int iBpi= GetDeviceCaps(hScreenDC ,BITSPIXEL);

    // Fill BITMAPINFO struct
    BITMAPINFO info;
    info.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    info.bmiHeader.biWidth = iScreenWidth;
    info.bmiHeader.biHeight = iScreenHeight ;
    info.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    info.bmiHeader.biBitCount  = iBpi;
    info.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

    // Create bitmap, getting pointer to raw data (this is the important part)
    void *data;
    hBitmap = CreateDIBSection(hMyDC,&info,DIB_RGB_COLORS,(void**)&data,0,0);
    // Select it into your DC
    SelectObject(hMyDC,hBitmap);

    // Copy image from screen
    BitBlt(hMyDC, 0, 0, iScreenWidth, iScreenHeight, hScreenDC , 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    // Remember to eventually free resources, etc.
```

It's been a while since I did this so I may be forgetting something, but that's the gist of it. A word of warning: this is NOT fast; when the screen is moving a lot, it may take 50ms or more to capture one frame. It's basically doing the equivalent of pressing the PrintScreen key.

Comment: Ha, Jonathan got it a few seconds before me. But it's nice to know we had the same answer.

Comment: What Could be an alternative that would capture the screen faster?

Comment: @Cover You could use a [mirror driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff568315(v=vs.85).aspx); apparently that's what's used by Remote Desktop Services. Or you could buy a video capture card.